# Проблема с установкой opencv 3 под python 3 на windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

Имеется:
 opencv-3.1.0
 python-3.5
 машина с windows 10

Скачал opencv с [pythonlibs](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) в формате whl.
Установил через pip, в консоли windows работает, проблем нет.

Но в среде IDLE не находит модуль 'cv2'

Сама устанвелнная библиотека (opencv) находится не в папке с питоном, а в папке анаконды.
Как я понял среда IDLE имеет доступ к поддиректориям папки Python35.
Думаю импортировать в папку с питоно, либо прописать путь в IDLE к папке с анакондой, но незнаю как сделать не криво.
Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: скорее всего у вас несколько Питонов установлено и вы пытаетесь `import cv2`, когда opencv библиотека установлена на другой Питон. [Устанавливая библиотеку на один Питон, вы не делаете её доступной для другой версии Питона](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/601003/23044)¶ Если пакет не чистый Питон, то вероятно бинарные установщики собранные  Gohlke не совместимы с Питоном, собранным для Anaconda. Если вы начали пользоваться Анакондой, то ставьте версии, предназначенные для Анаконда (отдельный мир). Попробуйте: [`conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/menpo opencv`](https://goo.gl/yNuPsn)

Answer (score -1):

Скопируй opencv***.whl в папку ...python35/Scripts и установи cv2 (pip install opencv**.whl). 
Анаконда и idle это разные программы.
Проверка установленных пакетов команда pip list, в папке Scripts, через консоль.