# Ошибка при форматирование формы из Qt в PyQt

Tags: python, qt

Установил python версии 3.5(галочку поставил add path, путь дефолтный) и pyqt4
Сам питон стоит тут:

> C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32

PyQt стоит тут:

> C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4

В path пути имеются

При форматировании простенькой формы из qt designer в формат pyqt получаю такую ошибку:

> C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4>pyuic4.bat form.ui -o project.py
>   ""C:\Python34\python"" не является внутренней или внешней командой,
>   исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

Подскажите что я не так делаю?

Answer (score -1):

Как вы могли бы догадаться, `PyQt4`, который вы установили, предназначен для работы с `python 3.4`. Поэтому у вас есть 2 варианта:

1) Если вам нужен именно `python 3.5`, то вам придется установить `PyQt5`, т.к. официального установщика `PyQt4` для данной версии питона не существует.

2) Если вам нужен именно `PyQt4`, то советую сначала удалить уже установленный `PyQt4`, установить `python 3.4` или `python 2.7` последней ревизии, затем снова установить `PyQt4` для соответствующей версии `python`.

Comment: совпадение цифр версий это случайность. К примеру, PyQt4 может поддерживать Python 3.3 или PyQt5 вероятно будет с Python 3.6 работать.

Comment: Ссылочку на `PyQt4` для `python 3.5` в студию.

Comment: Если кто-то решил, что мой ответ основан на совпадении цифр версий `PyQt` и `python`, то он ошибается. Мой ответ основан на фактах, а не домыслах. С официального сайта можно скачать установщик PyQt4 для `python 2.7` или `python 3.4`, версии для `python 3.5` нет. В вопросе автора указан путь установки, и он говорит о том, что использовался установщик для `python 3.4`. На `python 3.5` нет официального установщика `PyQt4`, также он не устанавливается через pip.

Answer (score -1):

Установка библиотеки для одной версии Питона, в общем случае, не делает её доступной для другой версии Питона.

Если вы хотите использовать библиотеку на Питоне 3.5, то и ставьте её на Питон 3.5, а не 3.4.

Comment: Поделитесь, как вам без бубнов удалось установить `PyQt4` на `python 3.5`. Совсем недавно мне это было очень нужно, не смог.

Comment: @Nikmoon: это отдельный вопрос.

Comment: Официальная версия установщика `PyQt4` есть только для `python 2.7` и `python 3.4`. Поэтому вопрошающий не сможет сделать то, что вы ему советуете.

Comment: @Nikmoon: это не имеет отношения к вопросу о том, что если у вас два питона, то в общем случае следует библиотеку под каждый Питон ставить. В качестве отдельного вопроса: если не можете самостоятельно это сделать, то можно спросить как поставить PyQt4 на Python 3.5 (на своей системе, я бы что-нибудь вроде: `sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt4` попробовал для начала, так как это библиотека с большой C зависимостью--если это не работает, то уже дальше разбираться--но это *отдельный* вопрос от установки библиотеки для одной версии и попытки использования её с другой версией Питона).

Comment: У автора вопроса как раз и не установлено двух версий питона. Он установил 3.5, а PyQt4 для 3.4. И пытается запустить интерпретатор 3.4, которого в системе вообще нет. Вот в чем проблема. А вы даете какой то общий ответ на какой то общий вопрос. Еще и минусанули, не разобравшись. И данном конкретном случае этот общий ответ неверный, см. коммент выше.

Comment: @Nikmoon: А что в моём ответе написано? Из мести голосовать не хорошо.

Comment: И в других темах минусанули) Как это по-детски, смешно.

Comment: Минус поставил за неправильный ответ,  вовсе не из мести. Что-то еще объяснять смысла уже не вижу.